# TwitterKit 3.0.4 - ITMS-90535: Unexpected CFBundleExecutable Key

Tags: ios, twitter, twitterkit

Since I updated to TwitterKit 3.0.4 I started receiving the following error once I try to upload my app to iTunes Connect.

> [Transporter Error Output]: ERROR ITMS-90535: "Unexpected
>   CFBundleExecutable Key. The bundle at
>   'Payload/Eventelis.app/TwitterShareExtensionUIResources.bundle' does
>   not contain a bundle executable. If this bundle intentionally does not
>   contain an executable, consider removing the CFBundleExecutable key
>   from its Info.plist and using a CFBundlePackageType of BNDL. If this
>   bundle is part of a third-party framework, consider contacting the
>   developer of the framework for an update to address this issue."

**Update:**
Update to TwitterKit 3.1.0 solves the issue.